# Function is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: c#, oracle

The below function return `VARCHAR2` datatype and it works fine:

```
select Get_Desc("45") from dual;
```

But when I am trying to run using C# I got error message on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00221: 'F_GET_DESC' is not a procedure or is undefined ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

```
public void Get_Desc()
{
    string oradb = "Data Source=source;User Id=myuser;Password=ss;";

    string CommandStr = "F_Get_Desc()";

    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(CommandStr, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OracleParameter pDesc = new OracleParameter("pDesc", OracleDbType.Varchar2,128);
        pOfficeDesc.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        pOfficeDesc.Value = Current_code.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pDesc);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show(pDesc.Value.ToString(););
    }
}
```

function code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Schema.F_Get_Desc(P_CODE VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_DESC VARCHAR2(64);

BEGIN
 IF P_CODE IS NULL THEN
  RETURN('');
 END IF;

 SELECT NAME_dsec
 INTO   V_DESC
 FROM   My_table
 WHERE  CODE = P_CODE;

 RETURN(V_DESC);
END;
/
```

Comment: Have you tried `Get_Desc()` instead of `F_Get_Desc()`?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code of the function you're calling. In addition, please show the name of the schema the procedure is defined in. Thanks.

Comment: @MT0 Yes I did @ Bob here is the fun code

Comment: You will also need to add a parameter that is an output to receive the return value of the function

Comment: as u can see I am adding in parameter

Answer (score 1):

problem solved by this way

```
public void Get_Desc()
    {
        string oradb = "Data Source=schema;User Id=user;Password=pwd;";

        string CommandStr = "F_Get_Office_Desc";

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(CommandStr, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("iCode", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Current_code;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("oDesc", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;                
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Current_Desc.Text = cmd.Parameters["oDesc"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the schema name in the command string?  Something like this.

```
string CommandStr = "Schema.F_Get_Desc()";
```

Also make sure that the user you are logging in as has access to the function and has the correct grants to execute.  You may have to specify the schema name in the command string if there is no public synonym for this function.

Comment: ORA-06550 line 1, column 7PLS-00801 internal error [22503]ORA-06550 line 1, column 7PL/SQL Statement ignored and i had two function on same schema and i am calling them by same way the only difference is that this one has parameter as u can see the first one is working but this wont be run

Comment: Try using `string CommandStr = "F_Get_Desc(pDesc)";`  You declared the OracleParameter but C# has no idea where to put it.